# Is it possible to listen to any kind of internet radio with HTML5 directly?

Tags: html, mp3, html5-audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

Is it possible to listen to any kind of internet radio with HTML5 directly? I mean is it posible to play live mp3 streams in HTML5 complaint browsers?

Comment: There's still no consensus over the audio format the <audio> tag will allow. Firefox, for one, doesn't read MP3s. Also, a stream is quite different from an audio file, so I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Take a look at the former specification of html5:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#attr-media-src

There is a huge load of specialities about streaming in html5.

And furthermore, take a look at this:
http://web.psung.name/zeya/ - a whole html5 media server.

---

**EDIT**

Actually it's like impossible to stream live media.
It's not that it'll stay impossible, but actually it isn't implemented at all - well none of the today's HTML5 browsers are going to support this in the next month's, because the real "live-stream", as known from flash (or equal) hasn't really been specified by the w3-committee - yet.

---

**2. EDIT**

As previous experiments showed, it may be possible to use streams without explicitly implement something specific for them. The "non"-stream way works on both streams and static files.

Comment: As I've  seen zeya just streams files...( And Specification is not too helpfull - I really need an example of any live stream radio playing...